# Initiating function in certain situations

Tags: javascript, jquery

basically I have something that's two different divs with users. One is for the assigned users, and others are unassigned. On clicking the trash icon, user is "unassigned" and therefore removed, but added to the unassigned users.

In the unassigned users div, you can click "Add" button to add each user to assined div.

I have managed to do that with the code below. However, once I unassign user I can assign it again right now. I supposed that's because newly added elements aren't working with the button click function that initiates process.

If I call one function inside the other, function runs twice each time button is clicked.

Can you help me with the code?

```
function assignUser() {
   $('.add-user-btn').click(function(){
   assign=$('#assign-users');
   $('<div class="assign-user"><div class="float-right delete-user-btn"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></div><h1>Name</h1></div><button class="btn"><span>Transfer online</span> </button></div>').insertBefore('.assign-user:last');
   $(this).parent().remove();
});
}


function unassignUser() {
  $('.delete-user-btn').click(function(){
    assign=$('#assign-users-modal');
    assign.append('<div class="assign-modal"><h5>Name</h5></div><button class="btn add-user-btn">Assign</button></div>');
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    parent.remove();
  });
}

  unassignUser();
  assignUser();
```

```html
<div id="assign-users">
  <div class="assign-user">
   <div class="float-right delete-user-btn"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></div>
   <h5>Stephen Meritt</h5>
   <button class="btn btn-xs btn-block transfer"><span>Transfer online</span</button>
 </div>

<div id="assign-users-modal">
  <div class="assign-modal">
  <h5>Test</h5>
  <button class="btn add-user-btn">Assign</button>
</div>
```

Comment: .`.remove();` is probably not the best resolution here,  Show the initial state HTML

Comment: This is a good case for [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) because of your dynamically created and removed elements.

Comment: This way a great suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because click event in both cases, add and delete, is bound on existing users at the time the JavaScript was loaded. When you assign/unassign a user, you are basically creating new elements dynamically which have no events bound to them.

You can use the following way to bind click event to fix it:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.add-user-btn', function () 
{ /* Code to move user to assign div */ }

$(document).on('click', 'div.delete-user-btn', function () 
{ /* Code to move user to un-assigned div */ }
```

Note that above will work only in the case when you are loading your js file once. In case you are loading your js file multiple times, click event will be bound to add and delete user buttons as many times as you are loading the js.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook event handlers to any pre-existing element when the page renders when the element will not go away.  Suggestion is to put a wrapper around the elements and use that as closest to the element as you can (avoids document and DOM traversal which can be expensive).

As an alternate rather than hitting the DOM often with add/remove causing re-flow you can also just put a set of elements in place in each and then toggle the visibility of them as I illustrate here.

I have put some styling and elements in place but more to show the actions and illustrate the toggle than to fully match any specific set of elements

```js
// just to set some use cases
let usersToSetup = [{
    name: "Fred Franklin",
    id: "fredid1"
  },
  {
    name: "Emily Emmerson",
    id: "emmy345"
  }
];
// setup some test case users from the list
function setup(users) {
  let au = $('.assign-users');
  let tu = $('.transfer-users');

  for (let u = 0; u < users.length; u++) {
    let user = users[u];
    // assign
    let uaclone = au.find('.user-row').eq(0).clone();
    let uac = uaclone.find('.user-name');
    uac.data('nameid', user.id);
    uac.html(user.name);
    au.append(uaclone);
    // transfer
    let utclone = tu.find('.user-row').eq(0).clone();
    let utc = utclone.find('.user-name');
    utc.data('nameid', user.id);
    utc.html(user.name);
    tu.append(utclone);
  }
}
setup(usersToSetup);

// event manager for the clicks, this be multiple events for actions if desired
$('#hold-stuff').find('.users-container')
  .on('click', '.transfer-user-btn, .assign-user-btn', function(event) {
    let userRow = $(this).closest('.user-row');
    let isHidden = userRow.hasClass('hidden');
    let userId = userRow.find(".user-name").data('nameid');
    let isAdd = userRow.hasClass('assign-user');
    let isRemove = userRow.hasClass('transfer-user');

    let users = $(event.delegateTarget) // the other group
      .siblings('.users-container')
      .find('.user-row');
    // get match(s) for this user, this wa in case of duplicates
    let userMatch = users.filter(function() {
      return $(this).find(".user-name").data('nameid') == userId;
    });

    userRow.toggleClass("hidden", true);
    userMatch.toggleClass("hidden", false);
    //might want to disable clicks if these take long then enable after
    if (isAdd) {
      // do add stuff
    }
    if (isRemove) {
      // do remove stuff
    }
  });
```

```css
body{font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands";}
.user-row.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.users-container {
  border: solid 1px #DDDDDD;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/js/all.min.js" integrity="sha256-qM7QTJSlvtPSxVRjVWNM2OfTAz/3k5ovHOKmKXuYMO4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="hold-stuff" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container-fluid transfer-users users-container">
    <div class="row header-text text-center">
      <div class="col">Transfers</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row user-row transfer-user hidden">
      <div class="col-sm">
        <h4 class="user-name" data-nameid="johnnytest">Johnny Test</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-xs transfer-user-btn" type="button"><span>Transfer online</span></button> 
        <span class="float-right transfer-user-btn"><i class="fas fa-redo"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container-fluid assign-users users-container">
    <div class="row header-text text-center">
      <div class="col">Unassigned</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row user-row assign-user">
      <div class="col-sm">
        <h4 class="user-name" data-nameid="johnnytest">Johnny Test</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm assign-user-btn"><span>Assign</span></button>
        <span class="float-right assign-user-btn"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```