# jquery call function from dynamic div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery. I have a div that is populated by jquery. Inside div, there is a list of items under `row` tag. And, Inside, the dynamic div section, I also have a anchor tag. On clicking on that anchor tag, I want to call the ajax function. Is it even possible?

```
var content='';

$.each(products, function(key, value) {
    content += '<div class="row">' +
                    '<img src="' + value.image + '" class="img img-responsive" style="height: 65px;"/>' +
                    '<h3>' + value.name + '</h3>' +
                    '<p>' + value.category + '</p>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<a href="#" data-id="' + value.product_id +'"  class="delete_product_from_space">Delete</a>' +
                '<hr>';
    });
modal.find('.modal_product_list').html(content);
```

When the anchor tag is clicked, I want to call ajax function. Here is my ajax sample:

```
$('.delete_product_from_space').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    alert('hello');

    var product_id   = $(this).attr('data-id');
});
```

The `on click` event is never fired. Is it possible to call like this? Or I am approaching in a wrong way?

Comment: Does your $.each... function run after $('.delete_... is loaded? You have to separately bind event to an element that is added dynamically.

Comment: No, first `$.each(products, function(key, value) {}` function load, it loads the content on div. and I want to call ajax from that content.

Comment: You might be running into similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/58364161/7046239

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to add the event on modal, as the dynamically generated elements would not be available at the time of code execution. Try the below code,

```js
$('.modal_product_list').on('click', '.delete_product_from_space', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('hello');
    var product_id   = $(this).attr('data-id');
});
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something on my code. Thank you. It's working now.